How insert data in MariaDB using docker and save changes of Database?
I am writing here  because I am new in Docker world. In the past, I was using Vagrant in developing stuff. Installing OS + packages that I need was very easy. Now, Vagrant is load more resources than I expected. I am changing to Docker and I made PHP environment. In docker-compose.yml load LAMP: Linux, Apache, MariaDB, and PHP as below.
services:
foo_php:
    build: .
    volumes:
        - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
        - 9002:80
foo_db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
        MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: Password1234
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    volumes:
        - ./mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin:latest
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 9003:80
  environment:
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1enter code here

and in Dockerfile, I made this:
FROM php:8.3-apache

MAINTAINER Senior Moe <m.kh.alnahdi@gmail.com>

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y && apt install libmariadb-dev -y

USER root

RUN sed -i -e "/^bind-address/d" /etc/mysql/my.cnf

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

Now in my sign up page, I made this:
    <?php
include_once "connection_db.php";

if(isset($_POST['your_name']) && isset($_POST['your_email']) && isset($_POST['your_passwrd']) && isset($_POST['repeat_passwrd']) ){
   function validation($input){
       $input = trim($input);
       $input = stripslashes($input);
       $input = htmlspecialchars($input);

       return $input;
   }

   $username = validation($_POST['your_name']);
   $user_email = validation($_POST['your_email']);
   $user_password = validation($_POST['your_passwrd']);
   $repeat = validation($_POST['repeat_passwrd']);

  
       $check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$user_email'";
       $result_check = mysqli_query($connection, $check_query);
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result_check) === 1 ){
           header("Location: ../index.php?registererror=The Email already exist");
           exit();
       }else{
           $hashed_password = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
           $record_db = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, user_email, user_password) VALUES (?,?,?)");
           $record_db->bind_param("sss",$username, $user_email, $user_password);
           header("Location: ../index.php?status=User Registe Seccessfully!");
           exit();
       }
   
}else{
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit();
}

In this post, I delete lines for validation to shortcut the question. In example above, if I test the sign up, the inserting not make insert in database.
Q1. How insert into database?
Q2. How save changes in database's structures after finish or for completing development in the future?
Updating:
Here, how I am connecting to database:
<?php

$server_db = [
    "server_name" => "foo_db",
    "server_user" => "root" ,
    "server_passwd" => "Password1234",
    "database_name" => "FOO_DB"
];

$connection = mysqli_connect($server_db['server_name'],$server_db['server_user'],$server_db['server_passwd'],$server_db['database_name']);

if(!$connection){
    echo "connection faild!";
}


keep the database file outside the container

@nbk do you know how to make it?

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278116/docker-compose-mariadb-external-volume-mapping-issue

@nbk database's structures are saved, but still I cannot insert any data.

For a start, restrict yourself to one container running PHP code and another with the DB. Then, how exactly are you running that code? Also, how exactly are you determining that it does not insert in database? Howe did you even set up the DB for storage? All those details with irrelevant parts removed make up a [mcve]. Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

@UlrichEckhardt, thanks for replay. The code are running normally when i put it in Vagrant or in local machine. The $_GET working after testing sign up form. I will update the question by putting how connected to DB.

@UlrichEckhardt @nbk The insert has been worked. the issue was not in connection. the issue was in php code by adding $record_db->execute();  $record_db->close(); thanks.

Don't "check, then insert", create unique key on user_email, then insert - and handle unique key violation error. This avoids a race condition. Compose files can use a volume: declaration.

To save Database make volume for database files by docker-compose.yml file:
services:
foo_php:
    build: .
    volumes:
        - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
        - 9002:80
foo_db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
        MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: Password1234
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    volumes:
        - ./mariadb:/var/lib/mysql #here
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin:latest
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 9003:80
  environment:
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
volumes:
  mariadb: #here

to write in database, the php was missing records:
<?php
include_once "connection_db.php";

if(isset($_POST['your_name']) && isset($_POST['your_email']) && isset($_POST['your_passwrd']) && isset($_POST['repeat_passwrd']) ){
   function validation($input){
       $input = trim($input);
       $input = stripslashes($input);
       $input = htmlspecialchars($input);

       return $input;
   }

   $username = validation($_POST['your_name']);
   $user_email = validation($_POST['your_email']);
   $user_password = validation($_POST['your_passwrd']);
   $repeat = validation($_POST['repeat_passwrd']);

  
       $check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$user_email'";
       $result_check = mysqli_query($connection, $check_query);
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result_check) === 1 ){
           header("Location: ../index.php?registererror=The Email already exist");
           exit();
       }else{
            $hashed_password = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
           $record_db = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, user_email, user_password) VALUES (?,?,?)");
           $record_db->bind_param("sss",$username, $user_email, $hashed_password);
       $record_db->execute(); //this was missing.
       $record_db->close(); //this for closing. 
           header("Location: ../index.php?status=User Registe Seccessfully!");
           exit();
       }
   
}else{
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit();
}

